# After deletion in vim, how can I automatically capitalize the new beginning of the sentence?

Tags: vim

I am writing my thesis in vim. Often, I realize that I want to remove the first few words of the sentence and, rather than write a different opening, simply capitalize the new beginning of the sentence. It would be nice if I didn't have to navigate to the beginning of the next word and toggle capitalization manually. (Note that this is a different problem than [wanting the first letter after sentence conclusion to be capitalized](https://superuser.com/questions/737130/automatically-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-sentence-in-vim).)

As a rule, when I want to do this, the deletion happens via `d(elete)` rather than `c(hange)`. But vim autocommands don't appear to differentiate between the two. Since I use `d`, I cannot hang this onto the `InsertLeave` autocommand, either.

Is there a way to do this? Is there a way to do this *without* defining a separate deletion command?

Answer (score 1):

If you do the usual normal mode deletion from the beginning [of the sentence] with `[count]dw`, your cursor will already be on the new first word. Then, a simple `~` will toggle its case. I think it can't get any simpler than that! Sure, you could write a custom command (but handling the motion like `d{motion}` isn't trivial to implement), but you'd probably have to map this to something longer than a single key, so nothing is won there.